# Countif function (excel) in R

Tags: r, apply, frequency, countif

I have a dataset "a" with a column "id" with about 23,000 rows, which are unique in this dataframe. I want to count the appearance frequency of these unique values in another two datasets "b" and "c". 
To do this, I tried the code:

```
count1 <- as.data.frame(apply(a,1,function(x)sum(b$id==x[45])))
a <- cbind(a,count1)
```

, since "id" is the 45th column in the dataframe "b".
The code works for counting in b, but when I tried the same code for counting the frequency of "id" in dataframe "c":

```
count2 <- as.data.frame(apply(a,1,function(x)sum(c$id==x[17])))
```

"id" in dataframe "c" is in the 17th column. The frequencies of all "id"s are counted as 0, which is not the case it should be. Could anyone suggest where the problem is or how to fix this problem?

Comment: This is an excellent example of why it is a bad idea to present failed code; rather it is preferred to post a minimal example describing the goal and input and output. Usually one would expect a COUNTIF problem to be solved with sum(logical expression).

Answer (score 2):

We can actually do this in a way that might at first seem a little weird, but is relatively straight forward. Let's start by working with just data frames `a` and `b` and let's simplify things a bit. Let's assume that the `id` variable in both `a` and `b` are the following:

```
a_id <- 1:5
b_id <- 1:5
```

In this simple example, `a_id` and `b_id` are exactly identical. What we want to know is how many times each of the values in `a_id` shows up in `b_id`. We obviously know the answer is one time each, but how do we get R to tell us that? That's where the `table` function can come in handy:

```
table(a_id, b_id)
#     b_id
# a_id 1 2 3 4 5
#    1 1 0 0 0 0
#    2 0 1 0 0 0
#    3 0 0 1 0 0
#    4 0 0 0 1 0
#    5 0 0 0 0 1
```

That might look a little ugly, but you can see that we have our `b_id`s on the top (1-5) and our `a_id`s on the left-hand side. Down the diagonal, we see the counts for how many times each value of `a_id` shows up in `b_id`, and it's 1 each just like we already knew. So how do we get just that information? R has a nice function called `diag` that gets the main diagonal for us:

```
diag(table(a_id, b_id))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 1 1 1 1
```

And there we have it. A vector with our "countif" values. But what if `b_id` doesn't have all of the values that are in `a_id`? If we try to do what we just did, we'll get an error because `table` doesn't like it when two vectors have different lengths. So we modify it a bit:

```
a_id <- 1:10
b_id <- 4:8
table(b_id[b_id %in% a_id])
# 4 5 6 7 8 
# 1 1 1 1 1
```

A couple new things here. The use of `%in%` just asks R to tell us if a value exists in a vector. For example, `1 %in% 1:3` would return `TRUE`, but `4 %in% 1:3` would return `FALSE`. Next, you'll notice that we indexed `b_id` by using `[`. This only returns of the values of `b_id` where `b_id %in% a_id` is `TRUE`, which in this case is all of `b_id`.

So what does this look like if we expect more than one value of each `a_id` in `b_id`, but not every `a_id` value to be in `b_id`? Let's look at a more real example:

```
a_id <- 1:10
b_id <- sample(3:7, 1000, replace=TRUE)
table(b_id[b_id %in% a_id])
#   3   4   5   6   7 
# 210 182 216 177 215
```

Like I said, it might seem a little weird at first, but it's relatively straight forward. Hopefully this helps you more than it confuses you.